Homotopy equivalence of open Euclidean sets implies diffeomorphism
Proposition: Let $n\geq 1$ and $~U,V\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ be nonempty, open and (weakly) homotopy equivalent. Then $U$ and $V$ are diffeomorphic.
Intuitively, I think this has to be true. Open subsets of Euclidean space are some of the simplest types of manifolds and thus should be classified up to number of connected components and $n$-dimensional analogue of genus, hence by $H_0$ and $H_{n-1}$ for any adequate homology theory. It should be a fairly simple to prove, yet I don't know where to start, mainly because I have not internalised yet how to actually use the fact that two spaces are homotopy equivalent in any proof that isn't about their homotopy and homology. Open subsets of Euclidean space are smooth as they have no boundary points, hence no "cusps" or "corners" or "singular points" and inherit a smooth structure from the ambient space, so the existence of a homeomorphism implying the existence of a diffeomorphism should be immediate, but I am more interested in the existence of a homeomorphism. Any ideas?
Edit: It has been brought to my attention that the necessary existence of a diffeomorphism is false because of inequivalent smooth structures in the fourth dimension. I still wonder about the existence of a homeomorphism. It seems like it should be true.
Extra question: Does anything change if I make the same statement for $U,V\subseteq\mathbb C^n$, since now they have holomorphic structure?

It's false. Look up (small) exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$'s. Also you seem to suffer from the misconception that that open subsets of Euclidean space are somehow easy to understand: any closed smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be "thickened" to an open submanifold with the same homotopy type (look up the tubular neighborhood theorem).

+Ben Steffan So guide me here. If a small exotic $\mathbb R^4$ $\hat U$ can be smoothly embedded as $U\subseteq\mathbb R^4$, then the embedding $f:\hat U\to U$ is a diffeomorphism, but there is no diffeomorphism between $\hat U$ and $\mathbb R^4$, hence no diffeomorphism between $U$ and $\mathbb R^4$, either. Did I get this right? If so, this is another complication in the fourth dimension when it comes to nonequivalent smooth structures, as it was with spheres. But a homeomorphism should still exist, right?

Yes, that would be correct. Homeomorphism cannot distinguish between different exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$s, and in all dimensions other than 4 there is a unique smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Note that @BenSteffan's comment about thickening disproves your intuition that open sets in $\mathbb R^n$ should be classified by $H_0$ and $H_{n-1}$. Not even all the homology groups together determine the open set, not even up to homotopy equivalence.

Google "Whitehead manifold".

@BenSteffan Why not an official answer?

You would have better luck if you require the homotopies to be smooth or relax diffeomorphism to homeomorphism. Even then, I believe it's still false in both cases, I think it's possible to construct a counterexample using the lens spaces.

There are many counter-examples even to the conjecture about homeomorphism, even if you consider contractible manifolds. For instance, Whitehead manifold is a contractible open subset of $\mathbb R^3$ not homeomorphic  to $\mathbb R^3$. The interior of every Mazur manifold is contractible, homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb R^4$ but not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^4$ (unless the bounding homology sphere is the ordinary 3-dimensional sphere).
Your conjecture fails even in 2-dimensional case (but not among contractible open subsets, of course):
The complement to the Cantor set in $\mathbb R^2$ is homotopy-equivalent but not homeomorphic to the complement to the subset
$$
\{(n,0): n\in \mathbb Z\}\subset \mathbb R^2.
$$
There are other examples as well among knot complements in $\mathbb R^3$, e.g. complements to the granny knot and square knot have isomorphic fundamental groups (hence, are homotopy-equivalent) but are not homeomorphic.

The complement of the Cantor set is a surface of genus 0 and with an infinity of ends, so it is  homeomorphic to ${\bf R^2} \setminus {\bf Z}$. The Kerékjártó's Theorem classifies  all surfaces...see [7] I. Richards, “On the classification of noncompact surfaces”, Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 106 (1963), p. 259-269.

@Thomas: No, one has only countably many ends and the other has continuum of ends. These are different cardinalities. It is a general fact that a homeomorphism of spaces induces a homeomorphism of their spaces of ends.

This is false : the set of ends of a manifold is always compact, as the inverse limit of finite sets (unbounded connected components of complementary of compact balls)...

@Thomas Of course it is compact, where did I say it was not? What I said is that the sets of ends have different cardinalities. Incidentally, your description of the set of ends is wrong (one takes complements to compact subsets, not to "compact balls").

@Thomas: One set of ends is homeomorphic to the 1-point compactification of $\mathbb N$, i.e. to ${0}\cup {\frac{1}{n}: n\in \mathbb N}$, while the other is homeomorphic to the disjoint union of the Cantor set and a singleton. Both are compact, of course, but with different cardinalities. There are also more interesting examples of planar surfaces with the same cardinality but not homeomorphic sets of ends.

Does anything change if we replace $\mathbb R^n$ with $\mathbb C^n$? Do open sets of complex space always have holomorphic structure?

The question is topological, the extra complex structure makes no difference. As for your last question, you should think about definitions a bit. If you cannot figure it out, write a new post with this question. Just make sure to include your thoughts.
